# Возвращает `None`, в книге ошибка?

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
def binary_search(my_list,item):
   low = 0
   high = len(my_list) - 1
   while low <= high:
      mid = (low + high)
      guess = my_list[mid]
      if guess == item:
         return mid
      if guess > item:
         high = mid - 1
      else:
         low = mid + 1
   return None

my_list = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
print(binary_search(my_list,7))
```

Возвращает `None`, в книге ошибка ? потому что я вроде ничего не пропустил... есть тут какая то ошибка

Comment: mid = (low + high) 
эту часть я думаю можно и без скобок написать, еще не понимаю почему как центр берется конец массива ? low = 0 high = len (list) | low + high = high

Comment: Для получения середины диапазона нужно взять среднее арифметическое нижней и верхней границы (сложить и поделить на два), а не просто сложить: `mid = (low + high) / 2` Если в книге без деления, значит опечатка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Запустил скрипт](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) на `python` и получил верный результат: номер позиции 3. Единственное, что у вас есть ошибка в табуляции:

```py
def binary_search(my_list,item):
   low = 0
   high = len(my_list) - 1
   while low <= high:
      mid = (low + high)
      guess = my_list[mid]
      if guess == item:
         return mid
      if guess > item:
         high = mid - 1
      else:
         low = mid + 1
   return None

my_list = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
print(binary_search(my_list,7))
```

Comment: Да, только из-за того что нет деления пополам получается не бинарный поиск, а линейный с конца.

Comment: @insolor полностью согласен, но тут вопрос в нерабочем коде с `None`, а не про бинарный ли это или нет. Так-то да, суть бинарки в делении на 2.

Comment: Первый комментарий под вопросом от автора вопроса: "еще не понимаю почему как центр берется конец массива ?", можно считать это продолжением вопроса

Comment: @insolor, но это уже два вопроса в одном) Не будем спросить, замечания все дельные